# Ubuntu eclipse javadoc does not show

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, javadoc

When using eclipse I get:

> The Javadoc for this element could neither be found in the attached source nor the attached Javadoc.

when hovering over code even for classes like `java.lang.String`.
Pressing Ctrl and selecting `Open Declaration` or `Open Implementation` yields:
[image]
I am running `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` using eclipse `version 2020-09 (4.17.0)` and have java OpenJDK installed:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 13.0.4 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.4+8-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.4+8-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode)
```

[image]
[image]

Clicking on `Change Attached Source...` in `String.class` (image above) I get this:
[image]

I cannot seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: According to `java --version` you have only a Java `Runtime Environment` (JRE without sources) instead of a JDK with sources. There are OpenJDK JREs and OpenJDK JDKs which might be a bit misleading.

Comment: The Source code is normally in a `src.zip` file in the lib directory and is only included in the JDK